# Why is my CSS Sprites not being applied?

Tags: html, css, css-sprites

I'm using CSS sprites in my code. The following is the background image that I use.

[image]

Inside HTML I have used a `span` to generate the icons dynamically based on a integer value (count) and the icon corresponding to that count should be displayed to the user.

```css
.molecularmatch-icon-image {
  width: 29px;
  height: 29px;
  line-height: 29px;
  display: block !important;
}

.molecularmatch-icon-image.count0 {
  background-position: -5px -0px;
}

.molecularmatch-icon-image.count1 {
  background-position: -34px -0px;
}

.molecularmatch-icon-image.count2 {
  background-position: -34px -34px;
}

.molecularmatch-icon-image.count3 {
  background-position: -63px -34px;
}

.molecularmatch-icon-image.count4 {
  background-position: -5px -68px;
}

.molecularmatch-icon-image.count5 {
  background-position: -34px -68px;
}

.molecularmatch-icon-image.count6 {
  background-position: -63px -68px;
}

.molecularmatch-icon-image.count7 {
  background-position: -5px -102px;
}

.molecularmatch-icon-image.count8 {
  background-position: -34px -102px;
}

.molecularmatch-icon-image.count9 {
  background-position: -63px -102px;
}

.molecularmatch-icon-image.count10 {
  background-position: -63px -0px;
}

.molecularmatch-icon-image.countexceed-10 {
  background-position: -5px -34px;
}
```

```html
<span>
  <span class="annotation-module__annotation-item__1DwWp">
  <i class="molecularmatch-icon-image count7" 
  data-test="molecularmatch-icon-image" style="background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTR2u.png);">
  </i>
  </span>
</span>
```

However when run this on browser only the CSS rules corresponding to `molecularmatch-icon-image rule` is applied on the icons. As a result all the icons display the initial icon in the sprite (count 0). When I add the second rule

```
.molecularmatch-icon-image.count7 {
  background-position: -5px -102px;
}
```

using browser's developer tools it seems to work correctly. Can anyone tell my what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you set a `Fiddle` for this or is there an `online link` we can check.?

Comment: unless path to the image is not right,, nothing seems wrong with your code https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WEedLm (i updated your snippets into a single one and also the image path )

Comment: Putting all icons in one line in sprite would make the math simpler.

Comment: Thanks for the help! i have used the image correctly in my code but the actual problem was related to rule name generated in my css file (molecularmatch-module.scss) for the count rules not being equal to the class name i set for the element (icon). Its resolved now.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't use the image in your CSS and the way the count classes were used was slightly wrong. Please see below.

```css
.molecularmatch-icon-image {
  width: 29px;
  height: 29px;
  line-height: 29px;
  display: block;
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTR2u.png');
  background-position: 0 0;
}

.count0 {
  background-position: -5px -0px;
}

.count1 {
  background-position: -34px -0px;
}

.count2 {
  background-position: -34px -34px;
}

.count3 {
  background-position: -63px -34px;
}

.count4 {
  background-position: -5px -68px;
}

.count5 {
  background-position: -34px -68px;
}

.count6 {
  background-position: -63px -68px;
}

count7 {
  background-position: -5px -102px;
}

.count8 {
  background-position: -34px -102px;
}

.count9 {
  background-position: -63px -102px;
}

.molecularmatch-icon-image.count10 {
  background-position: -63px -0px;
}

.molecularmatch-icon-image.countexceed-10 {
  background-position: -5px -34px;
}
```

```html
<span class="molecularmatch-icon-image count7"></span>
<i class="molecularmatch-icon-image count5"></i>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! i have used the image correctly in my code but the actual problem was related to rule name generated in my css file (molecularmatch-module.scss) for the count rules not being equal to the class name i set for the element (icon). Its resolved now.

Comment: Great. Like I said, the way the count classes were used was slightly wrong. Good luck with your project.